# Git hook written in python on Windows

Tags: git

How can I set the path for python on Git hook on Windows platform?

I have tryed:

```
#!/c/Python/27/python.exe
```

but got error:

```
error: cannot spawn .git/hooks/post-commit: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `#!/usr/bin/env python` instead is probably easiest. But your main problem in that particular case might be that usually it's `Python27`, not `Python/27`.